# Images not Being Display in BeanStalk Server

Tags: angularjs, laravel, mongodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lumen

My website is deployed on AWS Beanstalk server. on 27 July images were uploaded that were showing. but Today I saw images have vanished, not being displayed. While newly uploaded images are being displayed fine.

What can be the reason? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason could be due to the fact that your EB instance runs in an [Auto Scaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html).

This means that it can be terminated and launched at any time without your involvement. This can happen due to scaling events,  AZ re-balancing, or some aws hardware failures.

Thus its generally not recommended to store any data (e.g. images) on the instances. For that its better to use external storage systems, such as S3 or EFS.

The other reason could be the re-deployment of your application version. If you had sorted the images in your app's current working folder, the redeployment would simply remove it, and replace it with a new one.

Comment: I have not deployed any new build, is there any way to bring them back?

Comment: @AliBhutta Sadly not, unless you have your own backups. If your EB instances was indeed replaced, images are gone.

Comment: its bad news for me, anyway thanks

Comment: @AliBhutta You can always ssh into the instance and inspect from the inside, if they are there, just to be sure.

Comment: sure, I'll try it. Thanks